# Unable to view launched xpra session on web browser

Tags: html, linux, x11, x11-forwarding

[image]I am using xpra on centos 7 , I used the below command to start xpra:

`xpra start --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:8080 --start=xterm`

After starting xpra session, when I connect from chrome using http://0.0.0.0:8080/ IP it shows only the blue screen it does not show the xterm.

On checking the console of the development tools, I saw an error that 'ReferenceError: XpraClient is not defined'. I don't know what is causing this error.

I installed the xpra on this machine with command

`sudo yum install xpra`

and all the dependencies are installed by yum.

I tried the same installation and starting the xpra session on a different machine which was successfull.

log file of the xpra session is below

```
2023-07-20 11:39:44,793 created tcp socket '0.0.0.0:8080'^[[0m
  2 2023-07-20 11:39:44,801 cannot use uinput for virtual devices:^[[0m
  3 2023-07-20 11:39:44,801  [Errno 2] Failed to open the uinput device: No such file or directory. Perhaps load the uinput kernel module first?^[[0m
  4 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
  5 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
  6 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
  7 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
  8 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
  9 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 10 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 11 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 12 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 13 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 14 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 15 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 16 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 17 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 18 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 19 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 20 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 21 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 22 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 23 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 24 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 25 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 26 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 27 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 28 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 29 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 30 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 31 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 32 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 33 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 34 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 35 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 36 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 37 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 38 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 39 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 40 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 41 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 42 _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
 43 _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
 44 
 45 X.Org X Server 1.20.4
 46 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
 47 Build Operating System:  3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
 48 Current Operating System: Linux hostname 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 19 16:18:59 UTC 2020 x86_64
 49 Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/os_vg-root ro spectre_v2=retpoline rd.lvm.lv=os_vg/root rd.lvm.lv=os_vg/swap rhgb quiet LAN    G=en_IN.UTF-8
 50 Build Date: 01 April 2020  05:04:29AM
 51 Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.4-10.el7
 52 Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
 53     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
 54     to make sure that you have the latest version.
 55 Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
 56     (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
 57     (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
 58 (++) Log file: "/run/user/21040/xpra/Xorg.S126864.log", Time: Thu Jul 20 11:39:44 2023
 59 (++) Using config file: "/etc/xpra/xorg.conf"
 60 (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
 61 2023-07-20 11:39:45,407 created unix domain socket '/run/user/21040/xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 62 2023-07-20 11:39:45,407 cannot create group socket '/run/xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 63 2023-07-20 11:39:45,407  [Errno 13] Permission denied^[[0m
 64 2023-07-20 11:39:45,416 created unix domain socket '/pathtodir/.xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 65 ^[[33m2023-07-20 11:39:45,416 Warning: missing sound module^[[0m
 66 2023-07-20 11:39:45,490 pointer device emulation using XTest^[[0m
 67 2023-07-20 11:39:45,508 serving html content from '/usr/share/xpra/www'^[[0m
 68 2023-07-20 11:39:46,298 OpenGL is supported on display ':20'^[[0m
 69 2023-07-20 11:39:46,298  using 'llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)' renderer^[[0m
 70 2023-07-20 11:39:46,501 D-Bus notification forwarding is available^[[0m
 71 ^[[33m2023-07-20 11:39:46,626 Warning: webcam forwarding is disabled^[[0m
 72 ^[[33m2023-07-20 11:39:46,626  the virtual video directory '/sys/devices/virtual/video4linux' was not found^[[0m
 73 ^[[33m2023-07-20 11:39:46,626  make sure that the 'v4l2loopback' kernel module is installed and loaded^[[0m
 74 2023-07-20 11:39:46,626 found 0 virtual video devices for webcam forwarding^[[0m
 75 2023-07-20 11:39:46,770 xpra is ready.^[[0m
 76 2023-07-20 11:39:46,772 xpra GTK2 X11 version 3.1.4-r3M 64-bit^[[0m
 77 2023-07-20 11:39:46,801  uid=21040 (parade), gid=21054 (parade)^[[0m
 78 2023-07-20 11:39:46,801  running with pid 126873 on Linux CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 Core^[[0m
 79 2023-07-20 11:39:46,801  connected to X11 display :20 with 24 bit colors^[[0m
 80 2023-07-20 11:39:50,205 printer forwarding enabled using postscript and pdf^[[0m
 81 2023-07-20 11:39:50,215 started command 'xterm' with pid 127037^[[0m
82 2023-07-20 11:39:50,292 watching for applications menu changes in:^[[0m
 83 2023-07-20 11:39:50,292  '/usr/local/share/applications'^[[0m
 84 2023-07-20 11:39:50,292  '/usr/share/applications'^[[0m
 85 ^[[33m2023-07-20 11:39:51,697 ffmpeg: vp8+webm encoding failed: could not open vp8+webm encoder context: Invalid argument^[[0m
 86 ^[[31m2023-07-20 11:39:51,712 Error importing nvjpeg encoder (enc_nvjpeg)^[[0m
 87 ^[[31m2023-07-20 11:39:51,712  libnvjpeg.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory^[[0m
 88 2023-07-20 11:39:51,716 376.6GB of system memory^[[0m
 89 2023-07-20 11:39:52,382 New unix-domain connection received^[[0m
 90 2023-07-20 11:39:52,383 New unix-domain connection received^[[0m
 91 2023-07-20 11:39:52,383  on 'pathtodir/.xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 92 2023-07-20 11:39:52,383  on '/run/user/21040/xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 93 2023-07-20 11:40:06,158 New unix-domain connection received^[[0m
 94 2023-07-20 11:40:06,158  on '/run/user/21040/xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
 95 2023-07-20 11:40:06,159 New unix-domain connection received^[[0m
 96 2023-07-20 11:40:06,159  on '/pathtodir/.xpra/hostname-20'^[[0m
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.